# How can I uninstall my Huawei modem on Mac?

Tags: macos, modem

I've installed many things trying to make this modem works, until I finally found [something that **should** work](http://www.huawei.com/pt/catalog.do?id=1628) on the official website.

Now it isn't working, and I hope if I uninstall all other things and start a clean install again it will.

I have no idea where and how it was installed, and I don't remember anymore where I got all stuff and even if I did, I don't think they came with any uninstall method. So, anyone could tell me how I can clean up all that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally solved it.

First I tried using [SuspiciousPackage](http://www.mothersruin.com/software/SuspiciousPackage/), a great Quicklook plugin to show some selected details information about Packages. But that didn't help. Thanks to that I figured it might not be a problem of bad installation after all.

Then I decided to look at the Console for All Messages and started trying to diagnose it and understand what was going on. Searched on google for the error message "Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/cu.HUAWEIMobile-Modem", found this [great link](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=1013363&p=4) and found **a** solution:

Create (or replace, I had no file tho) the file **/etc/ppp/options** with just these lines:

```
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
refuse-mschap-v2
```

Then configure it properly on the Network Preferences pane and that's it! :)

I'm just posting this from my new connection!

Answer (score 1):

Check this guide : [Uninstalling Applications in Mac OS X](http://guides.macrumors.com/Uninstalling_Applications_in_Mac_OS_X) and also try with this [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/AppCleaner/) Uninstaller.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried AppCleaner, it's great stuff. I'll probably use it more. :)